# How to fill a list

Tags: python, list, fill

I have to make a function that takes an empty list as first argument and n as secound argument, so that:

```
L=[]
function(L,5)
print L
returns:
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I was thinking:

```
def fillList(listToFill,n):
    listToFill=range(1,n+1)
```

but it is returning an empty list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Consider the usage of `extend`:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend(range(1, 6))
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l.extend(range(1, 6))
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you want to make a function (doing the same):

```
def fillmylist(l, n):
    l.extend(range(1, n + 1))
l = []
fillmylist(l, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

A function without an explicit `return` or `yield` returns `None`. What you want is

```
def fill_list(l, n):
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        l.append(i)
    return l
```

but that's very unpythonic. You'd better just call `range(1, n+1)` which also returns the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` for `n=5`:

```
def fill_list(n):
    return range(1, n+1)
```

Comment: The function should not return anything but fill the list passed to it with integers from 1 to n.

Comment: @LinusSvendsson: then remove the `return` from my suggestion.

Comment: the function should take two arguments, the list to fill and n!

Comment: @LinusSvendsson: my first suggestion does that.

Answer (score 2):

And a bit shorter example of what you want to do:

```
l = []
l.extend(range(1, 5))
l.extend([0]*3)

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def fillList(listToFill,n):
    listToFill=range(1,n+1)
```

you change only the pointer of listToFill, if you don't return the *new* pointer; the new pointer isn't available out of the function and you have still the pointer of your empty list (in outer scope).

Answer (score 0):

- If you do :

`def fillList(listToFill,n):
    listToFill=range(1,n+1)`

a new list is created inside the function scope and disappears when the function ends. useless.

- With :

`def fillList(listToFill,n):
    listToFill=range(1,n+1) 
    return listToFill()`

you return the list and you must use it like this:

```
newList=fillList(oldList,1000)
```

- And finally without returning arguments:

`def fillList(listToFill,n):
    listToFill.extend(range(1,n+1))`

and call it like this:

```
fillList(oldList,1000)
```

**Conclusion**:

Inside a function , if you want to modify an argument you can reassign it and return it, or you can call the object's methods and return nothing.
You cannot just reassign it like if you were outside of the function and return nothing, because it's not going to have effect outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this nice pythonic way:

```
>>> l = [i for i in range(3)]
>>> print (l)
[0, 1, 2]
```

Also, it enables you to do other useful fills like:

```
>>> l = [-1 for i in range(3)]
>>> print (l)
[-1, -1, -1]
```

```
>>> l = [i*i for i in range(3)]
>>> print (l)
[0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: These create new lists instead of "filling" lists like the OP wanted. Another Pythonic way to achieve the first two would be to unpack range object with `[*range(3)]` and multiply a list of int with `[-1] * 3`.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardJi. Good point about creating a new list instead of filling and thanks for the additional pointers on creating lists.