# Alternate for range in python

Tags: python

If I have to generate natural numbers, I can use 'range' as follows:

```
list(range(5))
```

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Is there any way to achieve this without using range function or looping?

Comment: I have to ask why?

Comment: Yeah, you could manually add each number to a list. Do you consider `xrange` an alternative?

Comment: @cricket_007 `range` returns a list in Python2 and a generator in Python3. So I guess he is using Python3, which doesn't have `xrange` ;)

Comment: That is a thin line your asking us to walk between- not using `range()` or loops.

Comment: Every solution is going to implicitly or explicitly have loops in it, here's one without `range`: `list(itertools.islice(itertools.count(), 5))`

Comment: Not Python, but the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions

Answer (score 5):

You could use recursion to print first n natural numbers

```
def printNos(n):

    if n > 0:

        printNos(n-1)
        print n

printNos(100)
```

Comment: Interesting solution...but technically still looping, isn't it?

Comment: @roelofs . Just uses a stack. Also, he just wanted an alternative to a range function or looping.

Comment: @ayhan . Why would this run forever ? :D

Comment: @NihalRp - I understand the stack, but it is essentially using the stack to loop over a series of numbers.  Not dissing your answer (I like it), but the OP's question isn't super clear...

Comment: @roelofs. True!

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660337/recursion-vs-loops, doesn't go into semantics, but does have an interesting comparison.

Comment: Should be `print(n)` not `print n`

Comment: @MichaelMaggs . depends on the version of python you are using. My answer is for v2.7 and your answer is right for v3

Comment: Sure. He seems to be using 3, as he gives `list(range(5))`

Comment: @MichaelMaggs . You can't tell that is v3 with that statement. It's the same for v2 also :)

Comment: Just use `from __future__` and you're golden either way ;-)

Comment: Most importantly, @FlyingDutchmann, does this satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 3):

Looping will be required in some form or another to generate a list of numbers, whether you do it yourself, use library functions, or use recursive methods.

If you're not opposed to looping in principle (but just don't want to implement it yourself), there are many practical and esoteric ways to do it (a number have been mentioned here already).

A similar question was posted here: [How to fill a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429794/how-to-fill-a-list).  Although it has interesting solutions, they're all still looping, or using `range` type functions.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Nihal's solution, but returns a list instead:

```
def recursive_range(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return recursive_range(n-1) + [n-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, you can do this without using `range`, loop or recursion:

```
>>> num = 10
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["seq", str(num)])
```

You can even have a list (or a generator, of course):

```
>>> num = 10
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> ls = check_output(["seq", str(num)])
>>> [int(num) for num in ls[:-1].split('\n')]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]
```

But...what's the purpose?

Comment: Can you provide a link to some documentation on this?  It seems a novel approach.

Comment: @roelofs I'm just [calling an external command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/5399734). POSIX command [`seq`](http://man.cx/seq) can print a sequence of numbers, which seems to be what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks!  We're having a discussion on whether OP meant **any** looping, or just looping it himself.  Cool solution :)